# Why cannot the original author of a question delete it when has existing answers?

Tags: support, closed-questions, original-poster

I re-asked the following the serverfault.com questions on superuser.com and I did not allow me to delete them on serverfault.com because of the following reason:

[Increase the refresh rate on my monitor](https://serverfault.com/questions/34032/increase-the-refresh-rate-on-my-monitor-closed)
https://serverfault.com/questions/25403/video-card-driver-causing-windows-vista-to-blue-screen-closed

> Sorry, this question cannot be
>   deleted: too many existing answers, or
>   upvoted/accepted answers

I did not like this feature because they were closed and I am the original author.

Comment: You should ask a moderator to open those questions and migrate them to SU. If you already asked the same questions on SU, you should then ask a moderator (like TheTXI) to merge the duplicates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be the original author, but the post is not just for you. Your post is for the benefit of the entire community **INCLUDING FUTURE VIEWERS**. If you were to delete your own content whenever you wish, you would be causing other people to lose their rep during recalcs if they spent the time to answer you and receive upvotes. You would also be preventing future viewers from looking at your question and learning from it.

If you feel it needs to be deleted, flag it for moderator attention and let them make the final call.

Comment: I flagged questions on serverfault.com.  I updated them on superuser.com to pinpoint the exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

Other people have contributed content by that point - you're not just deleting your question, but their content.

If you were the only one to have posted anything, I'd see it as entirely reasonable for you to delete it - but if someone else has put work into answering it, why should you delete their work?

As TheTXI says, raise it with a moderator - they may be able to move the answers over too, and then delete the questions. That would make sense IMO: no content lost.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff has explained it here

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/adventures-in-delclusionism/